# how to set an attribute in a nested object in Python?

Tags: python, object, nested, nested-attributes, setattr

I'm making my first attempts at Python.

I need to loop over a log, parse log entries and then update an object, which includes nested objects for machines listed in the log.

This is what I have:

```
import re
format_pat= re.compile( 
    r"(?P<host>(?:[\d\.]|[\da-fA-F:])+)\s" 
    r"(?P<identity>\S*)\s" 
    r"(?P<user>\S*)\s"
    r"\[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s"
    r'"(?P<request>.*?)"\s'
    r"(?P<status>\d+)\s"
    r"(?P<bytes>\S*)\s"
    r'"(?P<referer>.*?)"\s'
    r'"(?P<user_agent>.*?)"\s*' 
)

from json import JSONEncoder
class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
      return o.__dict__ 

# JSON response object
class ResponseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, dict):
      self.__dict__ = dict


# check for JSON response object
try:
    obj
except NameError:
    obj = ResponseObject({})

test = ['2001:470:1f14:169:15f3:824f:8a61:7b59 - SOFTINST [14/Nov/2012:09:32:31 +0100] "POST /setComputer HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "-" 102356']

# log loop
for line in test:
  try:
    # try to create object from log entry
    m = format_pat.match(line)
    if m:
      res = m.groupdict()
      res["status"] = int(res["status"])

      # register machine if not done
      if not hasattr(obj, res["user"]):
        setattr(obj, res["user"], {"downtime":"0","flag":"false","downstart":"0","init":res["time"],"last":"","uptime":"","downtime":"","totaltime":""})


      machine = getattr(obj, res["user"])
      flag = machine["flag"]
      start = machine["downstart"]
      down = machine["downtime"]
      last = machine["last"]

      print "done"
      # set last
      last = res["time"]

      # PROBLEM this does not work
      setattr(machine, last, res["time"])
      print machine

    else:
      print "nope"
  except:
      print "nope base"

print MyEncoder().encode(obj)
```

The error I'm getting when trying to `setattr()` is

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute ''
```

but I was afraid it was not as easy as this...

**Question:**
How do I update the `last` value in my nested object using 'setattr'? Or is there another way to update nested object attributes?

Comment: "...but I was afraid it was not as easy as this..."?  It's actually *easier* than you were thinking.  Sounds like it would help to familiarize yourself with Python [data structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) such as the [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: well... true. First day with Python :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
setattr(machine, 'last', res["time"])
```

As [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) needs a string of the name of the attribute to be set

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Also I can use `setattr` further up in the code with a `res["user"]`

Comment: @frequeent But what do you want? You want machine to have an attribute named last, or you want it to have an attribute which name is inside the variable last?

Comment: machine should have an attribute `last` with the time of the log entry

Comment: @frequent Ok then you need to do exactly what is in my answer, what error are you getting?

Comment: it's still the same error ’AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'last'’. Your answer makes sense though. I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `setattr`. Just assign a value to the `"last"` key for each `machine` dictionary.

(actually you answered your own question!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but I can set the value of `last` like this:

```
  print machine
  print machine["last"]
  print res["time"]

  # this works
  machine["last"] = res["time"]

  print machine
```

If someone can explain, would be nice :-)

Comment: `machine` is a `dict`. That's why you can set the value of `"last"` key.